# Android seekbar rotation fails in android 2.2

Tags: android, rotation, seekbar

```
 <SeekBar
       android:id="@+id/seek_bar"
       android:layout_width="220dp"
       android:layout_height="70dp"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:max="100"
       android:progress="10"
       **android:rotation="270"** 
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_marginBottom="184dp"
       android:background="@drawable/blank"
       android:thumb="@drawable/blank"/>
```

The rotation part works in 4.0 perfectly but not in low android versions, how to solve it there?